# R vectorization - subtracting vectors

Tags: r, vectorization

Given an euclidean distance function:

```
eDistance <- function(q,m){
  apply(m,1,function(x){
    sqrt(sum((q-x)^2))
  })
}
```

And the following matrix:

```
t = cbind(c(3,4,1,6,3),c(1,9,1,2,1))
```

I want to find a vectorized way to do the following:

```
r = rep(NA,nrow(t))
for (i in 1:nrow(t)){
  tmp = eDistance(t[i,],t)
  r[i] = sum(tmp)
}
```

My main concern is performance time.

Thank You.

Comment: -1 with the two main problems (IMHO) being 1) no desired output. 2) code is broken (revisit `eDistance(c[i,],c)`)

Comment: You never define c. You also overwrite t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dist()` function. You want the column sums of this...

```
colSums(as.matrix(dist(t)))
#       1        2        3        4        5 
#13.22454 31.94863 17.64302 18.70368 13.22454
```